# How to extract sound files from an Android dictionary?

Tags: files

I downloaded a free dictionary (Teanglann) and would like to extract its sound files for free listening to facilitate language learning. I've already did a backup of the app in the .ab format and converted it to a .tar but cannot extract the contents in any way. I've used an emulator as it grants root access by default (that app's data is normally inaccessible - even through Solid Explorer ...). Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You if you try to extract Teanglann dictionary app then you won't find that's sound because sound file is store in your device 
When you install that application some options is suggest [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BPS7.png)

So steps that can extract sound file for you

1.Open Any file explorer and then go to internal storage [image: look like this]
May be the method is different from device to device 
2.go to Android-->data-->com.idmgroup.fng.retro (a folder name look like this) and after you can you see there is any sound file inside that's folder

This method does not give guaranty of success